# Hot to fetch only one field using Java DdynamoDB SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have such query

```
        var primaryKeyCondition = new Condition()
                .withComparisonOperator(EQ.toString())
                .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(pk));
        var sortingKeyCondition = new Condition()
                .withComparisonOperator(EQ.toString())
                .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(sk));

        var keyConditions = new HashMap<String, Condition>();
        keyConditions.put("pk", primaryKeyCondition);
        keyConditions.put("sk", sortingKeyCondition);

        QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest().withTableName(tableName)
                .withKeyConditions(keyConditions)
                .withProjectionExpression("photos");

        return client.query(queryRequest);
```

and Entity

```
public class Entity {
    @Id
    private PkSkPair dynamoId;
    private String pk;
    @DynamoDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = "gsi.bySk")
    private String sk;
    private String blaBla;
    private List<String> photos;
}

public class PkSkPair implements Serializable {
    private String pk;
    private String sk;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "PK")
    public String getPk() {
        return pk;
    }

    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "SK")
    public String getSk() {
        return sk;
    }
}
```

it fails with

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Unable to unmarshall exception response with the unmarshallers provided (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 3e1020d3-2f9b-4fff-82e2-d10cdd35a5d3)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1712)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1367)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1113)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:668)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:532)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:512)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.doInvoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:4805)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:4772)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.executeQuery(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2641)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.query(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2607)
    at com.transportexchangegroup.projection.vehicle.mobile.repository.VehicleCustomRepository.findByPkAndSk(VehicleCustomRepository.java:46)
    at com.transportexchangegroup.projection.vehicle.mobile.service.VehicleService.getPhotos(VehicleService.java:105)
    at com.transportexchangegroup.projection.vehicle.mobile.api.CommandController.performGetVehiclePhotosCommand(CommandController.java:120)
    at com.transportexchangegroup.projection.vehicle.mobile.api.CommandController.performCommand(CommandController.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
...
```

How to fix this and how to?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you *have* to just get the one field from the query? Why not instead go ahead and query as normal, then only take the field you need from your data object (i.e. entity.photos) Unless your documents in dynamo are gigantic and you're tryign to retrieve hundreds at once, there is not a lot of downside of doing it this way. There is much upside, giving you the ability int he future to reference the other attributes without having a new query

Comment: @lynkfox entity contains many fields, so it needed to skip other data. Photos list usually has only several items.